# Enable downloading from multiple sources using one URL w/o Apache2

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

Is there a way to enable a client actually download a file from multiple distributed source through one fixed link?

For example, a large file named `BigFile.tar.gz` was actually duplicated on `a.com/f.tar.gz`, `b.com/f.tar.gz` and `c.com/f.tar.gz`. A fixed download link is given to a client, `all.com/BigFile.tar.gz`.  Is there a way to configure a HTTP server, like using Apache2, to enable the client actually downloading the from `$(a-c).com/f.tar.gz` this 3 sources at same time?

New to web servers area. However, I managed to enable the `BigFile.tar.gz` can be downloaded from one of `$(a-c).com`, say `a.com/f.tar.gz`. To be exact, Apache2's **RedirectMatch** is used for this, as advised in https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache-tips-and-tricks/redirect-urls-with-the-apache-web-server .  It's a **one-to-one** mapping/redirecting.

But don't know how to enable **one-to-three** mapping.

Any advises?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a close look into mod_proxy module, specifically the mod_proxy_balancer module extension via https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html

Basically what you will want to do is set up the proxy directives like so:

```
<Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
    BalancerMember "http://192.168.1.50:80"
    BalancerMember "http://192.168.1.51:80"
</Proxy>
ProxyPass "/test" "balancer://mycluster"
ProxyPassReverse "/test" "balancer://mycluster"
```

This snippet was taken from the above link. To break it down for you, so you may better understand whats going on I'll go line by line.

```
<Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
```

This line is telling the Proxy module that you want to create an Apache load balancer called "mycluster"

```
BalancerMember "http://192.168.1.50:80"
BalancerMember "http://192.168.1.51:80"
```

These 2 lines is essentially saying have server A (50) and server B (51) in the load balanced cluster

```
ProxyPass "/test" "balancer://mycluster"
```

Here we essentially map the path `all.com/test` to then point to one of the 2 servers in our makeshift cluster

```
ProxyPassReverse "/test" "balancer://mycluster"
```

This line tells Apache to update some of the header lines with the information from the servers in your makeshift cluster

For this you will basically need 3 Apache instances or 3 servers setup. One will act as your load balancer and the other 2 would respond. You will need to make sure the content you want served is on all servers in your make shift cluster.

If you want `all.com` to show in the browser URL regardless of the load balance make sure you add `ProxyPreserveHost On` before `<Proxy "balancer://mycluster">`

Comment: many thanks for the info, clean, well-explained and really works.